# Найти изначальный базис в процентах если он не 100

Tags: математика

Задача следующая. Есть количество проданных билетов. Остаток в процентах, базис в билетах
Пример:

1. ?? - базис в процентах,
2. 50 - базис в билетах,
3. ?? - проданных билетов,
4. 30 - осталось билетов,
5. 60% - остаток в процентах.

Все просто. Мне нужно вычислить какой базис был в процентах. Я вычисляю это следующим образом:
60% + (50 - 30) / 50 * 100 = 100%
Вроде все работает норм. А что если базис изначальный был не 100% а 85. Как выйти на изначальный базис при таких условиях?

1. ?? - базис в процентах(в реальности был проставлен 85%, не 100),
2. 50 - базис в билетах,
3. ?? - проданных билетов,
4. 30 - осталось билетов,
5. 60% - остаток в процентах(теоретически должен быть другой).

Comment: Это так не работает. Тут не в процентах дело. У вас пропорция 50 — x, 30 — 60 -> x = 50 * 60 / 30 = 100. Если у вас должно быть 85, то зависимость непропорциональная, т.е. нелинейная. Т.е. у вас какая-то своя функция должна быть.